# Positive Definite Matrix of a Bilinear Form

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-element-method

I need to show that $a(u_{h},u_{h}) = u^{T}Au$ where $A$ is a symmetric $n \times n$ matrix and $a(u_{h},u_{h}) = ( \bigtriangledown u_{h},\bigtriangledown u_{h} ) = \int_{\Omega}\bigtriangledown u_{h} \cdot \bigtriangledown u_{h} dx $ and let $u_{h} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} u_{i} \phi_{i}$.

Solution: $a(u_{h},u_{h}) = ( \bigtriangledown u_{h},\bigtriangledown u_{h} ) = ( \bigtriangledown \sum_{j=1}^{n} u_{j} \phi_{j},\bigtriangledown \sum_{i=1}^{n} u_{i} \phi_{i}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} u_{i} u_{j} (\bigtriangledown \phi_{j}, \bigtriangledown \phi_{i}) $

I am not sure how to show this is equal to  $u^{T}Au$

Comment: You already have done that. Note that $$(\nabla \phi_j , \nabla \phi_i) = a(\phi_j , \phi_i) = A_{ji}$$ is the $(j,i)$-th entry of the bilinear form-matrix and $ \ u = (u_1 \dots u_n)^T$.

Comment: Yes I see that $A_{ji} = a( \phi_{j}, \phi_{i})$ but I am confused how to I get the $u^{T}$ and $u$ terms. Is this because I am summing over $(j,i)$? Thanks.

Comment: $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} u_{i} u_{j} (\nabla \phi_{j}, \nabla \phi_{i}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} u_{i} A_{ji} u_{j} = (u_1 ... u_n) \ A \left( \begin{array}{c} u_1 \\ \vdots \\ u_n\end{array} \right) = u^TAu$$

Comment: Excellent, I see now. That is what I was thinking but I was just a bit ambivalent about commuting $u_{j}$. Thanks again.